# How to aggregate the below records using awk command

Tags: awk

I have got the below records as input:`abc.dat`

```
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~12~0~1
```

now i need to aggregate the 11th,12th and 13th field based upon group by 1st till 10th field.

So that my output should look like :

```
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~192~0~16
```

tried the below :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="~";}{a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10]+=$11;b[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10]+=$12;c[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10]+=$13} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i],b[i],c[i]}' abc.dat > abc1.dat
```

but the output is coming like :

```
201901^Y230615^Y41302^Yblank^Yblank^Y05^YU099164^YARS^Yblank^Y030~192~0~16
```

an extra `^Y` symbol is coming.

Answer (score 1):

That's strange. It looks like `awk` is choking on the `~` when used inside the array keys. Probably because `~` is the match operator, but I'm not sure. In any case, this works as you want:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="~";}
       {
        key=$1"~"$2"~"$3"~"$4"~"$5"~"$6"~"$7"~"$8"~"$9"~"$10;
        a[key]+=$11;
        b[key]+=$12;
        c[key]+=$13
       } 
       END {
        for (i in a){
         print i,a[i],b[i],c[i]
       }
    }' file 
201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~192~0~16
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90264/discussion-on-answer-by-terdon-how-to-aggregate-the-below-records-using-awk-comm).

Answer (score 1):

If your fine with non-`awk` solutions, you might try `csvsql` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/), which would be the perfect tool for this:

```
csvsql -H -d '~' --query '
    select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,sum(k),sum(l),sum(m)
    from file
    group by a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
' file
```

Output:

```
201901,230615,41302,blank,blank,5,U099164,ARS,blank,30,192,0,16
```

If you need the output to be `~` - delimited, add `| csvformat -D '~'`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method by using combination of awk and sed

```
awk -F "~" 'BEGIN{sum=0;add=0;wo=0}{sum=sum+$NF}{add=add+$(NF-2)}{wo=wo+$(NF-1)}END{$NF=" ";$(NF-1)=" ";$(NF-2)=" ";print $0,add,wo,sum}' filename | sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"| sed "s/ /~/g"
```

output

```
awk -F "~" 'BEGIN{sum=0;add=0;wo=0}{sum=sum+$NF}{add=add+$(NF-2)}{wo=wo+$(NF-1)}END{$NF=" ";$(NF-1)=" ";$(NF-2)=" ";print $0,add,wo,sum}' p.txt | sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"| sed "s/ /~/g"

201901~230615~41302~blank~blank~05~U099164~ARS~blank~030~192~0~16
```

Comment: would be cleaner to use `ENV {$NF = sum; $(NF - 1) = wo; $(NF - 2) = add; print}` (and then you don't need sed), but I don't think it's safe to assume every line in the user's *real* data has the same key.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this: `a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10]+=$11`
awk uses this as the key: `$1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3 SUBSEP $4 SUBSEP $5 SUBSEP $6 SUBSEP $7 SUBSEP $8 SUBSEP $9 SUBSEP $10`
where the individual elements are joined by the contents of the `SUBSEP` variable. By default this value is "\034".

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html

To accomodate this, use `BEGIN{FS = OFS = SUBSEP = "~"}`

Comment: Thanks alot...for explaining what was causing the issue.